# Framer Motion layout modal glitch when closing modal after first time

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I'm trying to code a modal using Framer Motion but I don't know how to get rid of a glitch.

I have several divs and each one morphs into a modal when clicked. For example, if I click on the first one, open the modal, close it and then click on another div to open the modal, everything works correctly.

The problem is when I try to open the modal from the same div in succession. When I first open the modal and close it, everything is fine, but the second time I click on the div and open the modal, when I close it, it glitches. I get a stretched version of the model right above where the modal should be and where the modal should be I get a stretched version of the div that opens the modal. I've included a screenshot, hopefully it's clearer. [screenshot of the split second when the glitch occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjX8y.png)

If I click on another div, everything goes back to normal. There seems to be a problem with morphing the same div into a modal multiple times in a row.

The modal is wrapped in an AnimatePresence component. If I don't put it around the modal, the glitch doesn't happen anymore because the exit animation isn't executed anymore, so I think it's something related to the AnimatePresence component.

Here is an example of code that reproduces the glitch

```
const Test = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedLayoutId, setSelectedLayoutId] = useState("");

  return (
    <motion.div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
      <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
        {isModalOpen && (
          <div
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              height: "100%",
              width: "100%",
              backgroundColor: "#00000055",
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              zIndex: 999,
            }}
            onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(false)}
          >
            <motion.div
              layoutId={selectedLayoutId}
              style={{
                width: "50vw",
                height: "400px",
                backgroundColor: "white",
                borderRadius: "20px",
                userSelect: "none",
                color: "black",
                fontSize: "30px",
              }}
            >
              This is an example
            </motion.div>
          </div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
      <motion.div
        style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "white" }}
        onClick={() => {
          setIsModalOpen(true);
          setSelectedLayoutId("1");
        }}
        layoutId="1"
      ></motion.div>
      <motion.div
        style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "red" }}
        onClick={() => {
          setIsModalOpen(true);
          setSelectedLayoutId("2");
        }}
        layoutId="2"
      ></motion.div>
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a Framer Motion bug?